# Redux Field Array field.get(), unable to change the input according to type

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using redux form. Here I'm changing input field according the selected field type. This code is working for all type expect number type. I'm getting all type inside this condition (date, number and string).

```
<div className="form-group">
  {fields.get(index).criteria ? (
   <div>
    {fields.get(index).criteria.type === 'date'
    ? (
     <DatePickerBox
      name={`${member}.value`}
      label="Select Date"
      value={fields.get(index).value} 
     />
    ) : (
     <Input
      name={`${member}.value`}
      type={`${member}.value`}
      label="Value"
     />
    )
   }
  </div>
 ) : (
  <Input
   name={`${member}.value`}
  type={`${member}.value`}
  label="Value"
 />
)}
</div>
```

Whenever I'm switching to date or string type the render element is changing perfectly fine but when I select number type the render element does not change to input.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: are you getting the `fields.get(index).criteria.type` as "number" ?

Comment: @ronen Yes, I'm getting it as number

Comment: what is being rendered instead of Input? nothing?